# What characterises the smell of alkane hydrocarbons?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, color, smell

I have heard that aromatic hydrocarbons smell fruity and like petrol. However, I understand that there is a class of hydrocarbons called alkane, as for example propane or butane. I wondered if I might identify them by smell or sight in the same way as aromatic hydrocarbons. If so, what would characterise them?

Comment: Methane is odourless. Higher terms are easy to smell and I would define them fuel like, but "less round - more dry" and not very intense. Think of lighter fuel. Note that alkane become non volatile already at n=7. I also suspect that the smell of oil gases is due at least in part to sulphur and other stuff.

Comment: Depends on the terroir... speaking crudely, some may be high sulfur (of course, that's only an impurity).

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23842/why-does-heptane-have-an-odour... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9278/are-all-pure-alkanes-alkenes-and-alkynes-tasteless-odourless-and-colourles

Comment: Usually, some other compounds like thiols are added to natural gas like butane and propane in order to ensure that they have a smell in the event of a gas leakage for safety reasons. Alkanes usually do not have a smell, at least not that I know of.

Comment: Cigarette lighters are typically fueled with butane. I don’t believe there are any odors added, so you can get an idea of the smell from one of those

Comment: Let us put it this way. Petroleum ether certainly smells even at analytical grade. It can be called fuel like. Smelling compounds can be present from the natural crude product and lowered down, or conversely added for safety. I must admit that I don't know if pure alkanes intrinsically smell, or it is always due to the presence of traces, but they at least smell fuel for real. If they don't smell it is ok, they are paraffines at the end. And it means they have low affinity to many chemicals, and perhaps to smell receptors, too :)